# texture baking artifacts

Tags: texture-baking, baking, artifacts, noise-reduction

[image]im having issues with baking a texture via blender. im only using a bsdf node with white and the sun as a light source. somehow it keeps coming up with these artifacts instead of being smooth with small amount of noise in the viewport. can someone help on how to fix this?

Comment: Which artefacts? The flat shaded(?) blocky appearance of the discs?

Comment: @Blunder the appearance, its supposed to be solid white with shadows but it looks very jagged. i've increased the sample thinking its noise but nothing.